# What can be said about $\sum a_n^{\frac{n-1}{n}} $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ are positive real numbers such that $$ \sum a_n$$ converges, what can be said about $$\sum a_n^{\frac{n-1}{n}} ?$$

---

To see how the land lies let's test a few standard cases.

- If we have a converging geometric series $a_n=aq^n, 0<q<1$, $a>0$, then for all $n\ge1$
  $$a_n^{(n-1)/n}=a^{(n-1)/n}q^{n-1}\le Aq^{n-1}$$ with $A=\max\{1,a\}$. Meaning that the new series is majorized by a converging geometric series.
- If $a_n=1/n^{1+\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$, another standard converging test series, then, for $n>2/\epsilon$, we have $(n-1)/n>1-\dfrac\epsilon2$, and consequently $$a_n^{(n-1)/n}<\frac1{n^{(1+\epsilon)(1-\epsilon/2)}}.$$ Meaning that we have again a converging majorant as the exponent is a constant $>1$.

But what happens in general?

Comment: Unless I'm grossly mistaken, if $|a_n|>1$ for all $n$, then the second series is convergent by the comparison test, at the very least.

Comment: See also: [If $\sum a_n$ converges and every $a_n$ is positive then $\sum a_n^{(n-1)/n}$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2867911), [If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum a_n^{1-1/n}$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2891237) and [An interesting exercise about converging positive series, involving $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^{\frac{n-1}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949143).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: Let
\begin{align} A &= \{n\in\mathbb{N}: a_n<2^{-n}\}\\
B &= \{n\in\mathbb{N}: a_n\ge 2^{-n}\}
\end{align}
(notice that $A\cup B = \mathbb{N}$). Then
$$\sum\limits_{n\in A}{a_n^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}\le\sum\limits_{n\in A}{2^{-(n-1)}}$$
while for $n\in B$, we have $a_n\ge 2^{-n}\implies a_n^{-1/n}\le 2$, and hence
$$\sum\limits_{n\in B}{a_n^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}\le\sum\limits_{n\in B}{2a_n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum a_n^{{(n-1)}/n}$$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}^{{n}/{(n+1)}}}{a_n^{{(n-1)}/n}}=\dfrac{\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big)}{\Big(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}\Big)}$$

Now let by root test $0<\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=k< 1$, then also we have ratio test $0<\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big)=l< 1$

Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}^{{n}/{(n+1)}}}{a_n^{{(n-1)}/n}}=\dfrac{\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big)}{\Big(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}\Big)}=\dfrac{l}{\frac{k}{k}}=l<1$$

Hence the series converges.

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$, then also $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big)=1$, then we can not conclude in this way.

In this case we can find a large $N,m_n\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n\sim \dfrac{1}{{m_n}^\alpha}$ for $n\geq N$, where $\alpha >1$. Then $a_n^{{(n-1)}/n}\sim \dfrac{1}{{m_n}^{\alpha(n-1)/n}}$. We can find $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\alpha(n-1)/n>1$, for $n\geq N_1$. Hence the series converges.

---

Note: I am not sure if $k=l$(need to prove). But not needed here.